# using of functions or views in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have made functions and views  in SQL server. I excuted them and they are successfuly stored.
Now what should I write to use these views or functions in another query?!

I have tried

```
select something
from   FunctionName;
```

but system doesn't recongnize the function.

the function is:

```
create function TableOfDecades () 
returns @functiontable table
(
    decadeBegin int,
    decadeEnd       int,
    NumOfMovies int
)
as
begin
    declare @movie1 int;
    declare @movie2 int;
    declare @movie3 int;
    declare @movie4 int;
    declare @movie5 int;
    declare @year1  int;
    declare @year2  int;

    select @movie1 = count(id)
    from MOVIE
    where year >=1350 and year <1360;

    select @movie2 = count(id)
    from MOVIE
    where year >=1360 and year <1370;

    select @movie3 = count(id)
    from MOVIE
    where year >=1370 and year <1380;

    select @movie4 = count(id)
    from MOVIE
    where year >=1380 and year <1390;

    select @movie5 = count(id)
    from MOVIE
    where year >=1390 and year <1400;

    declare @maxOfMovies int;
    set @maxOfMovies = -1;

    if( @movie1 > @maxOfMovies )
    begin
        set @maxOfMovies = @movie1;
        set @year1 = 1350;
        set @year2 = 1360;
    end

    if( @movie2 > @maxOfMovies )
    begin
        set @maxOfMovies = @movie2;
        set @year1 = 1360;
        set @year2 = 1370;
    end

    if( @movie3 > @maxOfMovies )
    begin
        set @maxOfMovies = @movie3;
        set @year1 = 1370;
        set @year2 = 1380;
    end

    if( @movie4 > @maxOfMovies )
    begin
        set @maxOfMovies = @movie4;
        set @year1 = 1380;
        set @year2 = 1390;
    end

    if( @movie5 > @maxOfMovies )
    begin
        set @maxOfMovies = @movie5;
        set @year1 = 1390;
        set @year2 = 1400;
    end

    insert into @functiontable
        select @maxOfMovies, @year1, @year2;

    RETURN;
end
```

that I excuted it and it saved in folder programmability->functions->table-valued functions

Comment: your question lacks a lot of information. how do you wish to use these views ? in php, c#, etc ?elaborate a bit

Comment: it should be Select FunctionName();

Comment: it is sql server @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @kya the language is sql

Comment: @AK47 I tried it but didn't work :(

Comment: As now you have converted it to return Table. Now your first query should work. that is Select * from TableOfDecades()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work ..

```
SELECT decadeBegin, decadeEnd, NumOfMovies
FROM dbo.TableOfDecades();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to specifically return a Table type before it can be used by another sql call.
see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

different implementations of SQL have different formats for referring to the Table-Valued Functions..